# Substitute for JQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

We all know jQuery removed `toggle(handler, handler[, handler])` since jQuery 1.9. 
However, I found it really inconvenient if I want to achieve this:

```
var count = 0;
$('ele').click(function() {
 if(count === 0) { 
  alert("count is 0");
  count += 1;
 }else {
  alert("count is NOT 0")
  count = 0;
 }
});
```

**I wonder if there is any more simple way as a substitue for `toggle()` ?**
I've looked for an adequate answer for a while but failed...maybe it's because I missed sth. **If possible, please tell me the reason why `toggle()` was deprecated as well.** 
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. I am not sure what you want to achieve. For more queries check the above given links, I think one of them would serve to your requirement.

Comment: I found an answer in another question just now! Thanks anyway..